# Syntax hilighting for gcc warnings in bash

Tags: bash, syntax-highlighting, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

Is there a way to enable a hilighting scheme for gcc/g++ warning output? I'd like a simple way to spot (bright red?)  warnings from my compiler as the messages are streaming by.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032237/highlicht-and-filter-gcc-compiler-messages

Comment: This question comes up once a week im sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html