# Is there an easy way to COLOR-CODE the compiler outputs?

Tags: gcc, g++, ansi-colors

gcc (or other compilers) often generate huge text output and it's very difficult to see where the error is or miss warnings. I've done some search but havn't found a clean simple solution to color code the compiler output (so for instance warnings are yellow, errors are red, etc...)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032237/highlight-and-filter-gcc-compiler-messages ; (try clang too, colors output all by itself and has great diagnostics)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49064031/4561887

Comment: Recent GCC are able of color messages

Answer (score 26, accepted):

here's an alternative if you are looking for something very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

make ${@} 2>&1 | perl -wln -M'Term::ANSIColor' -e '
m/Building|gcc|g++|\bCC\b|\bcc\b/ and print "\e[1;32m", "$_", "\e[0m"
or
m/Error/i and print "\e[1;91m", "$_", "\e[0m"
or
m/Warning/i and print "\e[1;93m", "$_", "\e[0m"
or
m/Linking|\.a\b/ and print "\e[1;36m", "$_", "\e[0m"
or
print; '
```

Just alias your make to this script and make sure it's executable...

Comment: Wish I could upvote this a dozen times.  Works in Cygwin too.

Comment: Just want to say this is fantastic and works like a charm, however as it's currently typed I got an error about "nested quantifiers in regex" and fixed by adding '\' to the '+' in "g++" and it worked great after that.

Comment: What does it mean "Just alias your make to this script and make sure it's executable..."? How should I use this script?

Comment: I believe he means to add an alias to your bashrc file such as <alias make='make-thisscript'> So that when you type in <make> the <make-thisscript> will actually run instead. This script then calls the actual make. Search for "setting permanent alias" for more information.

Comment: For me, error information, warnings, and successful compiling are all in green. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Slightly modified version, `perl -wln ... print;'`, put in a file, say colorlog.pl, allows alternate usage: `my_build_command | colorlog.pl` or `cat log.txt | color.pl`

Comment: I'm having same result as @narengi , all messages are in green, except error which are correctly in red. Any idea why?

Comment: Solution for all messages in green is what @MikeDannyboy said. Instead of g++  use g\+\+ and then all works like a charm ;)

Comment: Brilliant! Copy and pasted and worked first go! Thank you!

Answer (score 32):

[Gcc 4.9 seems to have added this feature](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html) via the `-fdiagnostics-color` flag:

Answer (score 15):

Debian and Ubuntu gives the `colorgcc` package for that purpose.

And I usually run `gcc` (and `make`) thru `emacs` with `M-x compile` then the messages are colorized.

#### addenda

[GCC 4.9](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) has a native colorization facility and [GCC 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/) - released end of April 2016 -  (and probably [GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5) too) is enabling it by default (when stdout is a terminal).

Comment: Just for sake completeness, one needs to pass `-fdiagnostics-color=always` in CFLAGS.

Answer (score 14):

Ok, I'll just leave a notice about my own (python based) tool also :)

It is called [Pluggable Output Processor](http://zaufi.github.io/pluggable-output-processor.html) and designed not only to colorize output of one particular program. Here is sample GCC output before:

[image: Pluggable Output Processor Before]
After:
[image: Pluggable Output Processor Before]

Comment: Looks interesting, but the instructions for installation don't work on ubuntu. I tried the "easy" pip command, which fails because several python packages were missing. Some of them I could find as ubuntu package, but not all (for example exitstatus). After running pip as root it installed something but afterwards I had only stuff in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/outproc (no any of the directories the installation instruction mention), and no 'bin' dir anywhere, no 'outproc' binary anywhere...

Comment: @CarloWood, this is a Python 3 package. I've just tried in a minimal Ubuntu 16.04 docker container: `apt-get install -y python3-{pip,setuptools,wheel}`, `pip3 install -U pip` and finally `pip install outproc` -- everything has installed w/o problems.

Comment: Ok, with those instructions I am able to get something to install (assuming the last two commands have to be run as root, too). But after that, I don't have `/usr/lib/outproc/bin` or `/usr/bin/outproc` that your webpage talks about that I'd have to symlink. I have no idea how to test this installation therefore. I found an 'outproc' in `/usr/local/bin` with the current date (so I assume that was just installed), but running it gives errors: `outproc -m g++ ... File "/usr/local/bin/outproc", line 11, in <module> ... sys.exit(main()) ...`

Comment: `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/outproc/cli.py", line 236, in main ... return a.run() ... File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/outproc/cli.py", line 182, in run ... log.eerror('Pipe mode not implemented') ... File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/outproc/logger.py", line 33, in eerror ... print(' \x1b[0;31;1m*\x1b[0m {}'.format(msg), file=sys.stderr) ... NameError: name 'sys' is not defined`

Comment: @CarloWood, thanks for your patient, `import` error I've already fixed in version 0.18, the docs [would be actualized](https://github.com/zaufi/pluggable-output-processor/issues/11)

Answer (score 11):

See [colorgcc](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html), a perl script that coulours the gcc output.

Answer (score 1):

## How to install and use colorgcc to colorize your gcc compiler output:

At least 3 answers here so far mention [colorgcc](https://github.com/colorgcc/colorgcc), but NONE OF THEM EXPLAIN HOW TO INSTALL IT! (And it's not obvious). So, here's how to install the latest version in Ubuntu!

1. Go [here](https://github.com/colorgcc/colorgcc) and click "Clone or download" --> "Download Zip". I saved it into "~/Downloads/Install_Files"
2. Navigate to it in your file browser and right click it and go to "Extract Here." I now have a directory called "~/Downloads/Install_Files/colorgcc-master".
3. Copy the "colorgcc.pl" script to "/usr/bin/colorgcc" to "install" it (be sure to use the correct directory according to where you extracted it above): `sudo cp ~/Downloads/Install_Files/colorgcc-master/colorgcc.pl /usr/bin/colorgcc`
4. Make it executable: `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/colorgcc`
5. Make the "~/bin" directory if it does not yet exist: `mkdir ~/bin`
6. *Make symbolic links that point to "/usr/bin/colorgcc" so that whenever you call `gcc` or `g++` it automatically calls `colorgcc` instead:

   - `ln -s /usr/bin/colorgcc ~/bin/g++`
   - `ln -s /usr/bin/colorgcc ~/bin/gcc`
   - (if you ever want to uninstall colorgcc for some reason just delete these symbolic links "~/bin/g++" and "~/bin/gcc", and the Perl script: "/usr/bin/colorgcc" and you're done)
7. Done!

Here is a sample `g++` output now when I call `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 time_until_overflow_2.cpp -o time_until_overflow_2`:

[image]

*Note: making these symbolic links in "~/bin" only works if "~/bin" is in your PATH variable in a location *before* the folder where the actual `gcc` and `g++` executables are located. To ensure you have "~/bin" in your path you can view the PATH variable contents with: `echo $PATH`. If you don't see "/home/YOUR_USERNAME/bin" at the beginning of your path, add it with: `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH`.

References:

See here for more info. and for where I originally learned most of these steps: https://imranfanaswala.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/setting-up-colorgcc/. Thanks Imran Fanaswala!

~[GS](http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [GilCC](http://www.onlysolutionssoftware.com/gilcc/) which is a Ruby tool that will convert GCC output to color in real-time. Right now you have two choices: Perl script (colorGCC) or GilCC and if you already work with Ruby you will like GilCC.

Unique to GilCC; GilCC has warning and errors counters and also shows compile time, very handy when you are trying to improve things. Because it is in Ruby it is cross platform. It is flexible and you can add more gems to customize it anyway you want.

The link to the download page is here.

https://github.com/gilmotta/GilCC

Answer (score 0):

Although GCC 4.9 has -fdiagnostics-color option to enable colored outputs to terminals, I have created a tiny tool called '[crror](https://github.com/bearmini/crror)' to get colorized compiler output.

It supports outputs from `make` as well. I can add colorize patterns for other tools if anyone requires.