# Trying to color code g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

My g++ compiler for some reason shows all errors and warnings to be white, making spotting them very tough. I'm open to anything that is easy to implement. I have come across two solutions, none of which I can implement successfully, and hence I'm here:

Option 1: 
I've read that the best choice is colorgcc: https://github.com/johannes/colorgcc 
I have gone through basically all the posts on how to set it up, but am still having trouble. Here's what I have done so far.

I'm new to programming, so I couldn't understand a lot of it. But this is what I've done so far. I've tried to follow what other people have posted to the best of my knowledge but to no avail.

```
~$ vim .colorgcc (copy pasted the colorgcc perl script in here)
~$ chmod +X .colorgcc
/usr/bin$ g++ -> colorgcc
-bash: colorgcc: Permission denied
```

Option 2: 
I've also read this post: [Is there an easy way to COLOR-CODE the compiler outputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922960/is-there-an-easy-way-to-color-code-the-compiler-outputs) 
but not sure I understand where to copy paste the code that is shown in the best answer.

I think the reason why I can't set this up is because there is a lot that I don't understand, so if you could provide a more beginner like answer, it would be much appreciated.

I have a gcc version of 5.0. And I'm using a Mac OS X  10.10.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `g++ -> colorgcc` is not the correct syntax for creating a softlink. Try `ln -s <source> <linkname>`.

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting permission denied (even with sudo)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html (look for "color")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got colorgcc working just fine with the following:

```
~$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johannes/colorgcc/master/colorgcc.pl
~$ chmod +x colorgcc.pl
~$ sudo cp colorgcc.pl /usr/local/bin/colorgcc
~$ cd /usr/local/bin
~$ sudo ln -s colorgcc g++
```

Comment: I did all that but I'm getting ln: g++: File exists

Comment: @jasonadams what does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/` display?

Comment: i'm displaying a large list of things which I'm not sure what they are. I have a total of 67936 of what appears to be files?

Comment: I just looked up what ls -l means, am I looking for a particular file?

Comment: @jasonadams Sorry, that should have been `ls -l /usr/local/bin/g++`

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 jadams  staff  1207184 Nov  3 11:37 /usr/local/bin/g++

Comment: @jasonadams K you'll need to figure out another place to put it, we can [discuss it in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74687/room-for-wavemode-and-jason-adams-about-colorgcc).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74727/discussion-between-jason-adams-and-wavemode).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gcc > 4.9 the compiler should be able to output color error messages. The option to configure this is `-fdiagnostics-color[=WHEN]`.  This should work just fine in the terminal application in OSX.

For previous versions of gcc, there are external tools (filters) like `colorgcc` that will be able to colorize the output for you. You can take a look at *wavemode* answer for how to set up `colorgcc`.